# Converting a code from dplyr to base R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to convert a two sets of code designed for dplyr into base R code as a package I use does not support dplyr. My code is below. Could anybody help converting it? I am not very experienced with base R.

```
#Annual average
riverObs %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Qobs)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(s1 = Qsim-Qobs, 
         s2 = abs(s1),
         s3 = sum(s2),
         s4 = sum(Qobs),
         s5 = s3/s4,
         s6 = 1-s5) %>%
  summarise(AAVE = mean(s6))


#Annual peak error, Qobs
riverObs %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Qobs)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  filter(Qobs == max(Qobs)) %>%
  select(year, Qobs) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Which package does not support `dplyr` ? You can try `data.table` package, it will be a lot more easier than going from dplyr code to base R code.

Comment: It's a package called Hydromad, used for hydrological modelling

Comment: Maybe it can solve your problem : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hydromad-users/64odDuIR8kg

Comment: Tried that already, there is an issue downloading the latest version of hydromad, which has the update to fix the dplyr / hydromad collision

Comment: Does adding `%>% as.data.frame` at the end help?

Comment: So the trouble is that I need to add the code above into a function which runs using hydromad. I need to unload dplyr prior to using hydromad. Therefore I cannot have any dplyr commands in the code at all, e.g. mutate etc.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I assume that the following is your problem: You can't use `dplyr` together with `hydromad` because there are collisions between the two packages. E.g. there are functions with the same name in both packages.

One way to work around this issue is to, instead of loading `dplyr`, call its functions as follows: `dplyr::filter`, `dplyr::select`, etc. One thing you do have to account for is that to use the pipe `%>%` you would have to load the `magrittr` package.

Comment: The pipe can be used if he loads the package that provides it : `magrittr`

Comment: @MbrMbr Added :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(data.table)

riverObs <- as.data.table(riverObs)
riverObs <- na.omit(riverObs)
riverObs[,year:=(year(date))]
riverObs[,s1:=(Qsim-Qobs),by="year"]
riverObs[,s2:=abs(s1)]
riverObs[,s3:=sum(s2),by="year"]
riverObs[,s4:=sum(Qobs),by="year"]
riverObs[,s5:=s3/s4]
riverObs[,s6:=1-s5,by="year"]
riverObs[,AAVE:=mean(s6),by="year"]

riverObs <- as.data.table(riverObs)
riverObs <- na.omit(riverObs)
riverObs[,year:=(year(date))]
riverObs[,max_Qobs:=max(Qobs),by="year"]
riverObs <- riverObs[Qobs == max(Qobs),]
riverObs <- riverObs[,.(year,Qobs)]
```